# How to create a custom field in python jira

Tags: python, python-jira

I'd like to store some extra information in a custom field. So I create a dictionary for my issue:

```
            issue_dict = {
            'project': 'PROJECT-TITLE',
            'summary': 'issue title',
            'description': 'issue description',
            'assignee': 'issue assignee',
            'issuetype': {'name': 'Bug'},
            'customfield': {'extra info'}
        }
```

and import it to jira like this:

```
new_issue = self.jira.create_issue(fields=issue_dict)
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: set(['extra info']) is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround that I found was to store the information in a comment instead and parsing `comment body`instead. It ain't pretty though.